# Wildfly 15 is not creating cluster when running on different machines

Tags: java, networking, wildfly, cluster-computing

I try to create a wildfly cluster. The wildfly's are running on different machines and get started with the following command:

```
./bin/standalone.sh -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone-full-ha.xml -Djboss.node.name=widlfyl1

./bin/standalone.sh -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone-full-ha.xml -Djboss.node.name=wildfly2
```

If they are running on the same machine, they find each other immediately and create a cluster. But not if they are running on different machines in the same network.

Did somebody have an info how to get this done?

I tried this with wildfly 15.

Normally they should start communicate over udp multicast 230.0.0.4

I cannot find any traffic on this address for wildfly.

Comment: Are these regular machines on wired regular LAN? Multicast is not possible in many cloud hosting setups, can be tricky under docker etc. WiFi often doesn't support multicast either. As your on linux, you probably just need to add a route to the pc so the multicast traffic knows which interface to use. There is good explanation of this as part of the jgroups documentation

Comment: Thanks for the response, but why can I communicate with normal java over this route? so if I send information to this port (in docker or on my machine), I can receive them from another machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by binding the Infinispan to my current IP address

```
./bin/standalone.sh -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone-full-ha.xml -Djboss.node.name=widlfyl1 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djgroups.bind_addr=$(ipconfig getifaddr en0) -Djboss.messaging.cluster.password=secretPW
```